# Scala - expected (String, NotInferedB1) actual (String, Double)

Tags: scala

I am writing the coursera assignment where the problem is to compute the value of the expression. I have provided the code below. In the computeValues method I get NotInferredB1 as expected datatype.

1. Could someone explain what is NotInferred data type is?
2. Could you also explain why it expects NotInferred, as I do not understand as values1 is declared as (String, Double).

Code below:

```
sealed abstract class Expr
final case class Literal(v: Double) extends Expr
final case class Ref(name: String) extends Expr
final case class Plus(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr
final case class Minus(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr
final case class Times(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr
final case class Divide(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends Expr

def getReferenceExpr(name: String,
                     references: Map[String, Expr]) = {
  references.get(name).fold[Expr] {
    Literal(Double.NaN)
  } {
    exprSignal =>
      exprSignal
  }
}

def eval(expr: Expr, references: Map[String, Expr]): Double = {
  expr match {
    case Literal(a)=> a
    case Plus(a, b) => eval(a, references) + eval(b, references)
    case Minus(a,b) => eval(a, references) - eval(b, references)
    case Times(a,b) => eval(a, references) * eval(b, references)
    case Divide(a,b) => eval(a, references) / eval(b, references)
    case Ref(name)  => eval(getReferenceExpr(name, references), references - name)
  }
}

import scala.collection.Map
var namedExpressions: Map[String, Expr] = Map("a" -> Plus(Literal(2) ,Literal(3)), "b" -> Times(Ref("a"),Literal(2)))

def computeValues(namedExpressions: Map[String, Expr]):Map[String, Double] = {
  var values1 = Map[String,Double]()
  namedExpressions foreach {
    case (key,val1) => {
      values1 +=  Map(key -> eval(val1,namedExpressions))
    }
    values1
    }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am working in scala worksheet and do not have anyother imports other than Map. Its values1 not value

Answer (score 0):

The below change worked:

```
def computeValues(namedExpressions: Map[String, Expr]):Map[String, Double] = {
  var values1 = Map[String,Double]()
  namedExpressions foreach {
    case (key,val1) => {
      values1 +=  (key -> eval(val1,namedExpressions))
    }
    }
    values1
  }
```